# Selenium WebDriver - Chrome issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver

Im wokring on a tool development that tests various services on Chrome browser. For each service I would need to launch a new tab on Chrome. I use the below code,

[image]

The first 2 new tabs works fine, when the 3rd tab is launched, the 1st tab's url is navigated to the one used for 3rd tab.

Not sure what's messing up. Need assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe when your loop enters second iteration, your if statement executes to true.

You can just do following:

```
for(String actual: handles){
    driver.switchTo().window(actual);
}
```

After execution of the above loop, your script will always point to last window opened.
Then you can do:

```
driver.get(URL + service + URL_);
```

outside the loop.

P.S.: If required, for more enhancement you can use below script:

```
private void switchToLatestBrowserWindow(WebDriver driver, Set<String> priorHandles)
{
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until( // keep trying to switch for 60 seconds
                        d -> {
                            Set<String> newHandles = d.getWindowHandles();

                            if (newHandles.size() != priorHandles.size()) {
                                log.Info("NewHandles Size not equal to PriorHandles size.");
                                String lastWindowHandle = "";
                                for (String windowHandle : newHandles) {
                                    lastWindowHandle = windowHandle;
                                }
                                log.Info("LastWindowHandle Id: " + lastWindowHandle);
                                d.switchTo().window(lastWindowHandle);
                                log.Info("Switched window to " + lastWindowHandle);
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
}
```

*priorHandles* is set of window handles retrieved before opening new window. (the first line of code, in your case). So complete snippet would look like:

```
Set<String> priorHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
((JavasriptExecutor) driver).executeScript( script: "window.open()");
switchToLatestBrowserWindow(driver, priorHandles);
driver.get(URL + service + URL_);
```